# Nested Attributes Forms for Has One

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build, relationship, nested-attributes

I am trying to use nested attribute forms with a relation that is belongs_to and has_one

I have defined the relations in my model like

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :account, dependent: :destroy

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :merchant
```

Controller

```
def edit
    @merchant = Merchant.find(params[:id])
    @merchant.account.build
    @states = State.form_selector
    @products = Product.all
    @properties = Property.where(property_set_id: 1)
  end
```

Error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/admin/merchants_controller.rb:32:in `edit'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build syntax for `has_one` association:

```
@merchant.build_account  # this will work

@merchant.account.build  # this will throw error
```

Read the has_one association [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001834) for more details.

Also, You should check if `@marchant` is found with the given `id`